# how to send Dtmf tone programmatically during a live call in android?

Tags: android, dtmf

I Want to send **DTMF** Tones programmatically in my app. While searching i found a method

`public void playDtmfTone (char digit)`

Is this a new update by google in android to send **DTMF** or still we have to wait.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html#playDtmfTone(char)

Answer (score 1):

There are the so called audio streams, and so there must be a way of playing tones over the `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` or `AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF` ones. Actually Skype does this.

But what you can't do for sure is to play tones over a call made from other app.

Comment: [SendDtmfThroughaActiveCall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073211/getting-java-lang-classcastexception-while-sending-dtmf-tones-over-an-active-calx#new-answer) the algro7 is follow the same approach for which is asked above ....can you plz check this out Because i am new to android

Comment: Can you refer me any solution regarding this problem @MisterSmith and thanx for replying