# ANDROID: Play an audio after recieving call

Tags: android

I am making an android application in which I have to answer the call and then I want to play pre-recorded audio so that the person calling will hear this.

Is there any API or any library which can I use for this?
Can we do it through text-to-speech ?

Thank you

Comment: hi, did you get the solution for this one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to play audio  during call in Android device.

> Note: You can play back the audio data only to the standard output
>   device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth
>   headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during
>   a call.

Link to android documentation 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer

For more information 
[How to play an audio file on a voice call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8784221/6059583)